# Can plug an air-conditioner into a outlet with an adapter

Tags: grounding

So I'm getting a window unit and I've read online that you should never plug an AC into a power strip or even use an extension cord. My room has no three prong(grounded) outlets, can I plug the AC into an adapter or do I need to pay someone to upgrade the outlet?

Comment: Asking random people on the internet rather than the local electritian,  sounds like a solid plan. Especially when we have no idea how your socket looks like, on in what country you live.

Comment: If you adapter is approved, it should have a maximum rating on it somewhere. Look for 'W',  'A' or 'VA'.

Comment: Do you mind being electrocuted if the air conditioning system develops a fault?  If the answer is "yes", then get an electrician in to wire it in properly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an extension cord to connect a window a/c unit, if the cord is heavy enough. Modern small units (5000 BTU/h) only pull about 4 A continuously. Just make sure that the connection between the extension cord and the cord for the a/c unit doesn't get pull partially out so the plug heats up.

Comment: Although I agree with Jim code has discouraged the use of cords for many years but a proper sized cord will work just fine.+

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to consider is how much current the air conditioner requires and how much current the receptacle can supply. Most USA wall outlets can supply 15 amps. Kitchen counter and bathroom outlets have long been required to supply 20 amps, but probably not at the time before grounded outlets were required. You need to first check the current requirement marked on the AC. If it has a standard 15 amp plug, it should require no more than about 80% of 15 amps, 12 amps or 13 amps. Check the fuse or circuit breaker for the outlet you want to use to determine the maximum current it can supply. Also check what other outlets are on the same fuse or breaker. After plugging in the AC, there may not be much capacity for other things plugged into the same circuit. If the circuit has the capacity, you can connect the AC.

Rather than use an adapter to accommodate the grounded plug, it would be better to install a GFI outlet in place to the old ungrounded outlet. I believe that code still allows that, but the outlet must be marked as ungrounded using the label provided with the outlet. (I checked your profile to determine that we are talking about a USA location.) Better than that but more expensive would be to add a ground wire. An electrician would need to determine how that can be done in an acceptable way.

If the AC does not have a standard grounded plug, it must require more than 13 amps. If it requires no more than 15 amps, it could be connected to the proposed circuit, but code requires that there be no other outlets on the circuit. If it requires more than 15 amps, it requires a higher capacity circuit.

Comment: GFCI'S do have problems with motor loads, I would change the outlet and run a single ground wire back to the panel this outlet is powered from or at the first 5 feet of the grounding electrode system where it enters the home with an approved clamp. More work but safer having a 3 prong so it won't pull out as easy and now the unit is properly grounded.

Answer (score 1):

It *could be done safely* but with inappropriate expectations for continuous oversight. So, it good advice for everyone to NOT use extension cords, loose old outlets, and "cheater" adaptors.

It could be safe if this outlet was properly installed and barely used, the house wiring / wall outlets in the path to this outlet was properly installed and has not degraded, the "cheater" 2-prong to 3-prong adaptor attached to a truly, verified grounded screw on the outlet, and an added heavy duty AC extension cord or commercial grade power strip are not old or worn. These multiple requirements would safely* power an air conditioner having an LCDI plug. But any inspector would reject this. And any of these possible and prevalent faults could burn your house down: a loose screw on any of the connections to the outlet being used; a less-then-firm grip on the prongs of the cheater adapter being used; or a moderately aged or cheap power strip likely relaxed contact pressure on the air conditioner plug prongs. Any of those reduce the true capacity from an original 15 amps to something much less, probably fine for electronics and a couple of table lamps. Any of these impairments WILL translate to the increased contact resistance(s), unwanted heating at contacts, beyond "a bit warm" if you grip the plugs after an hour of use. Moderate contact heating might exist as a safe-and stable level for a while, but over time increases as spring metal relaxes, temperature swings under screw heads compress copper wire, pollution infiltrates the connection, humans unplug and re-insert plugs, etc. until red-hot heating persists. Fuses and circuit breakers don't know this is happening. AFCI breakers might catch it if arcing occurs, and flame-retardant materials might prevent spread and contain the fire.

So, without expert assessment** of the house wiring and outlet health, and appropriate selection of modern and small size, low current air conditioners, and a practice of re-confirming performance... a safe and durable (long lasting) power connection is a matter of luck!

*"Safely" is said quite conditionally here...

**I even hate to suggest that an "expert assessment" is even available! I am an electrical engineer, have investigated several equipment fires, and former designer of swimming pool power, lighting and protection products... and still all I would do is to suggest a temporary use of adaptors and old outlets if I personally tested that particular outlet to my criteria of max 7 volts drop at 15 amp load for an hour, with other loads turned on, and a promise that if the AC is moved, the cord is kicked, if the plug isn't being monitored every hour for excessive heating, if the fuse or circuit breaker blows, if a different AC is used... then I automatically retract any opinion of it "being safe". That is a lot to ask!

Here is a good, and often mentioned option: Have the 2-wire receptacle replaced with a GFCI receptacle labeled "no equipment ground"; operate the AC directly plugged into this new outlet, and can verify the outlet voltage only dips less than 5 volts when turning the AC on, Fan HIGH, compressor running, and ALL other loads on the same circuit also turned on. This isn't a lot of work, and is much better than nothing.

- If you had to extend the power from this upgraded outlet, use a brand new, short, "Air Conditioner" or "Appliance" Extension Cord having 14 AWG wire and a UL or ETL safety listing. These, when new, will last until you do the next step...
- the BEST is if you have an electrician run a new, dedicated circuit to a new plug right at the window where the AC is to be installed.

TLDR

The Internet, CPSC, and most manufacturers say DON'T use cheater adapters and especially extension cords because house are burning down. Look at these [scary images](https://www.google.com/search?q=burnt%20extension%20cord&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS905US906&sxsrf=ALiCzsZvFE94IBnA0Sy0LyJpAHOO1HrylA:1661704016909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv5pjt-en5AhVNjYkEHY3XCBgQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1396&bih=596&dpr=2.75). [image] NFPA is only addressing new wiring with NEC code changes for new wiring. They COULD demand the LCDI plug would ALSO release if the contact prongs were getting hot. And UL COULD enable consumer-installable protection adaptors that would make safe use of space heaters and air conditioners in old houses much safer than what is being sold today.

I included an Internet picture showing how the last outlet's current of a typical circuit will flow through many (16 in this example) different wire to screw connections (I included the fuse box screws not shown).

Comment: Please [edit] to include the source of your "internet picture".